# What does it mean when one says something is SFINAE-friendly?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I can't clearly get the grasp of what it means when one mentions that a particular function, struct or ... is **SFINAE-friendly**.

Would someone please explain it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When it allows substitution failure without hard error (as `static_assert`).

for example

```
template <typename T>
void call_f(const T& t)
{
    t.f();
}
```

The function is declared for all `T`, even those which don't have `f`, so you cannot do SFINAE on `call_f<WithoutF>` as the method does exist. ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2738ca8a62c6356b) of non compiling code).

With following change:

```
template <typename T>
auto call_f(const T& t) ->decltype(t.f(), void())
{
    t.f();
}
```

The method exists **only** for valid T.
so you can use SFINAE as

```
template<typename T>
auto call_f_if_available_impl(const T& t, int) -> decltype(call_f(t))
{
    call_f(t);
}

template<typename T>
auto call_f_if_available_impl(const T& t, ...)
{
    // Do nothing;
}

 template<typename T>
 auto call_f_if_available(const T& t)
 {
    call_f_if_available_impl(t, 0);
 }
```

Note the `int = 0` and `...` is to order the overload.
[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb21f6f13915eeda)

--

An other case is when the template add special parameter to apply SFINAE for specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename Enabler = void> struct S;
```

And then

```
// Specialization only available for T which respect the traits.
template <typename T>
struct S<T, std::enable_if_t<my_type_trait<T>::value>>
{
};
```

Comment: Isn't `int = 0` vs `...` ambiguous?

Comment: What do you mean by: *you cannot do SFINAE on `call_f<WithoutF>`*?

Comment: @TartanLlama no it's not because `int` is __more specialized__ than `...`

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous. It won't compile.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Fixed, Thanks.

Comment: @tkausl But the ICSs for overload resolution don't prefer either for a call which uses the default argument. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/080986badbc23730).

Comment: Thanks for examples, I've been trying them. So at the end `auto call_f_if_available(const T& t)` is SFINAE-friendly, i.e. it will compile no matter if `f()` is available or not. but `auto call_f(const T& t) ->decltype(t.f(), void())` and `void call_f(const T& t)` are **not**. Correct? Can you add this info to make it clear too?

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny: `void call_f(const T& t)` is not SFINAE friendly as declaration exists even for invalid `T`. `auto call_f(const T& t) ->decltype(t.f(), void())` is friendly as for invalid `T`, the declaration won't be part of valid overload. Finally, `call_f_if_available` is valid for all `T` so it is irrelevant for Substitution failure.

Comment: Since you said without hard error! I thought that call_f_if_available suites that definition better, because there's no error.

Comment: With `->decltype(..)`, `call_f(WithoutF{})` is valid and error appears inside the body of the function `call_f` (too late to see that `call_f(WithoutF{})` is invalid). In the friendly version, the error is know from the declaration.

Comment: This explains what SFINAE is but not what it means for something to be SFINAE-friendly (e.g. N3462 & N3843).

Comment: @Oktalist: I show example only for function and not for struct. but same logic apply.

Answer (score 9):

An entity is termed SFINAE-friendly if it can be used in the context of SFINAE without producing a hard error upon substitution failure. I assume you already know what SFINAE is, as that is a whole other question in itself.

In the context of C++ standardization, the term SFINAE-friendly has so far been applied to `std::result_of` and `std::common_type`. Take the following example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x, typename std::common_type<T, int>::type y) {}

void foo(std::string x, std::string y) {}

int main()
{
    foo(std::string("hello"), std::string("world"));
}
```

Without SFINAE-friendly `common_type`, this would fail to compile, because `std::common_type<std::string, int>::type` would produce a hard error during template argument substitution. With the introduction of SFINAE-friendly `common_type` ([N3843](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3843.pdf)) this example becomes well-formed, because `std::common_type<std::string, int>::type` produces a substitution failure so that overload is excluded from the viable set.

Here's a similar example with `result_of`:

```
template <typename T>
auto bar(T f) -> typename std::result_of<T()>::type { return f(); }

void bar(int n) {}

int main()
{
    bar(42);
}
```

Without SFINAE-friendly `result_of`, this would fail to compile, because `std::result_of<int()>::type` would produce a hard error during template argument substitution. With the introduction of SFINAE-friendly `result_of` ([N3462](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html)) this example becomes well-formed, because `std::result_of<int()>::type` produces a substitution failure so that overload is excluded from the viable set.