# Is std::make_unique SFINAE-friendly?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, sfinae

I'm doing some template-meta-programming and I would like to implement a generic cloning function that selects a method of cloning depending on the validity of expressions via SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error).

On [this reference website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) it says that

> The function

```
make_unique<T>( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
```

> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
> ```

Does this mean that the following code

```
template <typename T>
auto my_clone( const T & t ) -> decltype( std::make_unique<T>(t) )
{
    return std::make_unique<T>(t);
}
```

should be completely equivalent to

```
template <typename T>
auto my_clone( const T & t ) -> decltype( std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(t) ) )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(t) );
}
```

even when I have other overloads of the function `my_clone`? In other words: is `std::make_unique()` [SFINAE-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033306/what-does-it-mean-when-one-says-something-is-sfinae-friendly)?

If `T` is **not** copy constructible, then the latter code would not participate in overload resolution due to SFINAE.

Here's a small example that fails to compile on GCC 5.3 with C++14 turned on:

```
#include <memory>

// It does **not** work with this snippet:
template <typename T>
auto my_clone( const T & t ) -> decltype( std::make_unique<T>( t ) )
{
    return std::make_unique<T>( t );
}

/* // But it works with this snippet instead:
template <typename T>
auto my_clone( const T & t ) -> decltype( std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(t) ) )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(t) );
}*/

// This is another overload for testing purposes.
template <typename T>
auto my_clone( const T & t ) -> decltype(t.clone())
{
    return t.clone();
}  

class X
{
public:
    X() = default;

    auto clone() const
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<X>( new X(*this) );
    }

private:
    X( const X & ) = default;
}; 

int main()
{
    // The following line produces the compiler error: 
    // "call to 'my_clone' is ambiguous"
    const auto x_ptr = my_clone( X() ); 
}
```

Comment: The standard does not guarantee it, so you should not rely on it.

Comment: @Holt What doesn't the standard not gaurantee?  in [unique.ptr.create] it states that `make_unique` *Returns*: `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes but the standard does not guarantee that `std::make_unique(Args&&...)` should not exist if `T` is not constructible using `Args&&...`.

Comment: @Holt Ah okay.  I just wasn't sure exactly what you were talking about.

Comment: In your case, you may use `std::is_copy_constructible` traits instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard only guarantees that:

```
template <class T, class... Args> unique_ptr<T> std::make_unique(Args&&... args);
```

...must returns `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`, it does not guarantee that the `make_unique` function should only exist if `T` is constructible using `Args...`, so it is not SFINAE friendly (per the standard), so you cannot rely on it.

The only section of the standard mentioning `make_unique`:

> §20.8.1.4 [unique.ptr.create]:
>
> ```
> template <class T, class... Args> unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> 1. *Remarks:* This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless T is not an array.
> 2. *Returns:* `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`.

In your case, you may want to either use the version with `std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(...))` or use `is_copy_constructible` to make your `my_clone` SFINAE friendly (@Yakk, @Jarod42), e.g.:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>>
auto my_clone(const T & t) -> decltype(std::make_unique<T>(t)) {
    return std::make_unique<T>(t);
}
```

Comment: Gotta love that triple negative :)