# Why can std::is_invocable not handle forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding

I have a class that is simply forwarding the function call to another class and I would like to be able to use `std::invocable<>` on my forwarding class. But for some reason that fails... Is this what I should expect? Is there a way to work around it?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
    constexpr int operator()( int i ) const {
        return i;
    }
};

struct ForwardToFoo {
    template<class ...Args>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()( Args &&...args ) const {
        Foo foo;
        return foo( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
};

int main( void ) {
    // These work fine
    static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<ForwardToFoo, int> == true );
    static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<Foo, int> == true );
    static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<Foo> == false );

    // This causes a compile error
    static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<ForwardToFoo> == false );

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
The answers so far suggest that the issue is that the last `static_assert()` forces `ForwardToFoo::operator()<>` to be instantiated without arguments hence triggering a compile error.
So is there a way to turn this instantiation error into a SFINAE error that can be handled without a compile error?

Comment: I think it would help me (and the OP of course) if the answers could explain why `static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<Foo> == false );` is fine but `static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<ForwardToFoo> == false );` is an error. That information seems to be missing

Comment: @Kevin - the difference is that `Foo::operator()()` doesn't exist where `ForwardToFoo::operator()()` exist (well... the compiler can generate it with `Args...` empty) but **inside** its body gives an error.

Comment: @max66 Your edit to your question explains that and the fix nicely, thanks

Comment: See also [What does it mean when one says something is SFINAE-friendly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35033306/2069064)

Comment: @Kevin - exactly: after the fix `ForwardToFoo::operator()()` doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the same error that you get from

```
ForwardToFoo{}();
```

you have that the `operator()` in `ForwardToFoo` is invocable without arguments. But when it call the operator in `Foo()`, without arguments... you get the error.

> Is there a way to work around it?

Yes: you can SFINAE enable `ForwardToFoo()::operator()` only when `Foo()::operator()` is callable with the arguments.

I mean... you can write `ForwardToFoo()::operator()` as follows

```
template<class ...Args>
constexpr auto operator()( Args &&...args ) const
   -> decltype( std::declval<Foo>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...) ) 
 { return Foo{}( std::forward<Args>( args )... ); }
```

**-- EDIT --**

Jeff Garret notes an important point that I missed.

Generally speaking, the simple use of `std::invokable` doesn't cause the instantiation of the callable in first argument.

But in this particular case the return type of `ForwardToFoo::operator()` is `decltype(auto)`. This force the compiler to detect the returned type and this bring to the instantiation and the error.

Counterexample: if you write the operator as a `void` function that call `Foo{}()`, forwarding the arguments but not returning the value,

```
template <typename ... Args>
constexpr void operator() ( Args && ... args ) const
 { Foo{}( std::forward<Args>( args )... ); }
```

now the compiler know that the returned type is `void` without instantiating it.

You also get a compilation error from

```
static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<ForwardToFoo> == false );
```

but this time is because `ForwardToFoo{}()` result invocable without arguments.

If you write

```
static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<ForwardToFoo> == true );
```

the error disappear.

Remain true that

```
ForwardToFoo{}();
```

gives a compilation error because this instantiate the operator.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see anyone mention, but it is relevant, and in a way the forwarding does come into play: is_invocable doesn't itself cause instantiation; it only uses the declaration. But the function uses a decltype(auto) return type so it is *that* which triggers instantiation. If the return type were known (say, int), the body would not be instantiated, and is_invocable would return true. (is_invocable does not answer can you call it without error. it answers whether the declaration says you can call it.)

Comment: @JeffGarrett - Good point. I've missed it. Added in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @iolo - answer improved following an important observation from Jeff Garrett.

Comment: That is really useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite work out why you expected this to work.

`Foo` requires an `int` to be callable, so `ForwardToFoo` does too. Otherwise its call to `Foo` will be ill-formed.

It doesn't really matter whether you're forwarding the arguments or copying them or anything else: they still have to be provided.

Think about how you would invoke `ForwardWithFoo`. Could you do it without arguments? What would happen?

Comment: I expect the last `std::is_invocable<...>` to be `false` and not a compiler error.

Comment: @iolo Ah I see. Perhaps you could have stated that in your question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to forwarding or not. In your last `static_assert` you request the compiler to instatiate the `ForwardToFoo::operator()` without arguments. Within that operator you call `Foo::operator()` which has only an overload taking an int. This is obviously causing a hard compiler error.

`std::is_invocable` works in the other cases as it does not actually instantiate the non-existing operators.

A potential fix to your code would be to force at least one parameter being passed to `ForwardToFoo::operator()`:

```
struct ForwardToFoo {
    template<class Arg0, class ...Args>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()( Arg0 arg0, Args ...args ) const {
        Foo foo;
        return foo(arg0, args...);

    }
};
```

Then, the compiler will not instantiate that operator (because it is not callable without parameter).

Or you can use expression-sfinae as showed in the other answer.

See [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/NiF4iN)