# C++ Concept to determine arity and type of functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

The following code intends to provide a concept for functions with a given signature and arity:

```
#include<utility>    //std::index_sequence
#include<cstddef>    //std::size_t
#include<functional> //std::invoke

struct A {};
struct B {};

auto f1 = [](auto) -> A { return {}; };  //should work also for generic arguments
auto f3 = [](A,A,A) -> A { return {}; };
auto g1 = [](B) -> B { return {}; };

//a unary A-function is a function A -> A
template<typename function_t>
concept is_unary_A_function = requires
{
    { std::invoke(std::declval<function_t>(), std::declval<A>()) } -> std::same_as<A>;
};

//an Nary A-function is a function with signature A x A x ... A (N-times) -> A
template<typename function_t, std::size_t N>
concept is_Nary_A_function = requires
{
    { []<size_t ... I>(auto function, auto a, std::index_sequence<I ...>)
        {
            return std::invoke(function, (I, a) ...);
        }(std::declval<function_t>(), std::declval<A>(), std::make_index_sequence<N>()) } -> std::same_as<A>;
};

static_assert(is_unary_A_function<decltype(f1)>);        //OK
static_assert(!is_unary_A_function<decltype(g1)>);       //OK
static_assert(!is_unary_A_function<decltype(f3)>);       //OK
static_assert(is_Nary_A_function<decltype(f3), 3>);      //OK
//static_assert(!is_Nary_A_function<decltype(f1), 3>);   //compile-time error
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cT7Y3a4Gh)

In words, the `is_unary_A_function` concept should be true if it is inserted a function `f1: A -> A`, i.e. a function which takes a parameter of type A and returns a type A. The `is_Nary_A_function` with a given arity `N` concept should be true for a function `fN : A x A x ... A -> A`, that is a function which takes N parameters of type A and again returns an `A`.

Here, in the `is_Nary_A_function` concept, the usual approach using index_sequences is applied to call the provided function with N parameters of type `A`.

However, as soon as I evaluate the the concept `is_Nary_A_function<decltype(f1), 3>`, I get a compile-time error stating *no matching function for call to 'invoke'* which basically complains that the compiler can't call `f1(a,a,a)`. However, the compiler also can't call `g1(a)`, which is checked in the `!is_unary_A_function<decltype(g1)>` expression, but this seems to work correctly.

Thus, the lambda closure in the N-ary function concept seems to make a difference. Can someone please explain a reason for that and show a possible workaround?

Comment: It looks like a big to me. The whole point of requires expression is not to give such an error (return false instead).

Comment: @Dmitry It's only false if the substitution error is in the immediate context of the expression in a requirement. This error happens when deducing the `auto` of the lambda (You also get a similar error if you try the exact same thing with SFINAE: https://godbolt.org/z/rnqKnhjrz )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making your lambda SFINAE friendly, your code works:

```
//an Nary A-function is a function with signature A x A x ... A (N-times) -> A
template<typename function_t, std::size_t N>
concept is_Nary_A_function = requires
{
    { []<size_t ... I>(auto function, auto a, std::index_sequence<I ...>)
    -> decltype(std::invoke(function, (I, a) ...))
        {
            return std::invoke(function, (I, a) ...);
        }(std::declval<function_t>(), std::declval<A>(), std::make_index_sequence<N>()) } -> std::same_as<A>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W9WdxEvvo).

Note: `requires` has syntax to allow to avoid `std::declval`:

```
//a unary A-function is a function A -> A
template<typename function_t>
concept is_unary_A_function = requires
{
    { std::invoke(std::declval<function_t>(), std::declval<A>()) } -> std::same_as<A>;
};
```

can simply be

```
//a unary A-function is a function A -> A
template<typename function_t>
concept is_unary_A_function = requires(function_t f, A a)
{
    { std::invoke(f, a) } -> std::same_as<A>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G9Tf91nEv)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please shortly explain why the trialing return makes the lambda SFINAE-friendly (... I would have assume the auto-return deduction would do exactly this). I also read your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033306/what-does-it-mean-when-one-says-something-is-sfinae-friendly) on the topic, which is basically what you get when searching for *SFINAE-friendly*, but it's not completely clear to me.

Comment: SFINAE happens on **declaration**, not **definition**. Trailing-return-type is part of declaration. auto-return type need definition to know the return type.

Answer (score 1):

I think the direction you are taking is a bit complicated.
This is the arity part of your problem the checking retval for void should not be too hard.

```
#include <utility>

// reusable constexpr for calculating arity
template <typename retval_t, typename... args_t> 
constexpr size_t get_arity( retval_t(*fn)(args_t...))
{
   return sizeof...(args_t);
}

// for C++17 these constexpr can be useful in their own right
// but they will also be used to setup the concepts later
template <typename fn_t>
static bool constexpr is_unary(fn_t fn)
{
    return (get_arity(fn) == 1ul); 
}

template <std::size_t N, typename fn_t>
static bool constexpr is_n_nary(fn_t fn)
{
    return (get_arity(fn) == N); 
}

// C++20 concepts
template <typename fn_t>
concept IsUnary = is_unary(fn_t{});

template <std::size_t N, typename fn_t>
concept IsNnary = is_n_nary<N>(fn_t{});

// And the tests
void unary_fn(int a)
{
}

void foo(int a, int b, int c) 
{
}


// use the concepts to setup functions that accept functions
void apply_unary(IsUnary auto fn)
{
    fn(1);
}

void apply_ternary(auto fn) requires IsNnary<3,decltype(fn)>
{
    fn(1,2,3);
}


int main()
{
    static_assert(get_arity(foo)==3ul);
    static_assert(is_unary(unary_fn));
    static_assert(is_n_nary<3>(foo));
    apply_unary(unary_fn);
    //apply_ternary(unary_fn); correctly does not compile
    apply_ternary(foo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One downside of this function-pointer approach is that it doesn't work with generic functions such as `void foo(auto a, auto b, auto c)`, but to be honest, I have not included that requirement in my question .. but have added it now.